# Maximum and minum value using loop function

Tags: python-3.x

I want to find the the minimum and maximum value with loop without using the list function.  The code works perfectly I just get the same maximum as minimum value?

```
import math

Choice= ''
sum=0

while Choice!='3':
    print ('1- Amount of rain per month')
    print('2- See statistic for this year')
    print('3- Finish')
    val= input ('Your choice:')

    if Choice== '1':

        for x in range (1,13):
            rain= input ('Give the number of month'+ str(x)+ ':')
            rain=float(rain)
            sum+=rain
            print('Sum:', sum)

    if val== '2':
        print('The average in a year:', sum/12)
        minVal=0
        minVal<rain
        minVal=rain
        print('Minimum value:', minVal)
        maxVal=0
        rain > maxVal
        maxVal=rain
        print('Maximum value:', maxVal)


if Choice=='3':
        print('Finish')
```

Comment: ... works perfectly and max==min contradicts itself ...

Comment: `rain > maxVal` is a comparison that returns True or False ...but you do nothing with it. You also only have the total sum - not the single month-values stored. You would need to store the values of the months into a list - then you can loop over the list and get the min and max values. Or you define min/max first and on input when new jnumber is bigger/lower adjust your "memorized" min/max-values. Fixing this would mean to rewrite your whole code - you might want to browse some tutorials to get the hang of lists and loops.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it this program that you want?

```
import math

val= ''
sum=0
count=0
min=0
max=0

while val!='3':
 print ('1- Amount of rain per month')
 print('2- See statistic for this year')
 print('3- Finish')
 val= input ('Your choice:')

 if val== '1':

  for x in range (1,13):
    rain= input ('Give the number of month'+ str(x)+ ':')
    rain=float(rain)
    if count == 0:
      min = rain
      max = rain
      count=1
    else:
      if (min > rain):
          min = rain
      if (max < rain):
          max = rain
    sum += rain
    print('Sum:', sum)

 if val == '2':
     print('The average in a year:', sum / 12)
     print('Minimum value:', min)
     print('Maximum value:', max)
 if val == '3':
     print('Finish')
```

Comment: I tried this code and I still get the same maximum value as minimum value

Comment: You can write second codes(starting with if(count==0) ) under the rain=float(rain) ,because It is more.I shared all codes for you as unified .

Answer (score 1):

```
Choice= ''
sum=0
minVal = 0
maxVal = 0

while Choice!='3':
    print ('1- Amount of rain per month')
    print('2- See statistic for this year')
    print('3- Finish')
    Choice = input ('Your choice:')

    if Choice== '1':

        for x in range (1,13):
            rain= input ('Give the number of month'+ str(x)+ ':')
            rain=float(rain)
            sum+=rain
            print('Sum:', sum)
            if minVal >rain or minVal == 0:
                minVal = rain
            if rain > maxVal or maxVal == 0:
                maxVal = rain

    if Choice == '2':
        print('The average in a year:', sum/12)
        print('Minimum value:', minVal)
        print('Maximum value:', maxVal)


if Choice=='3':
        print('Finish')
```

This is the solution of your problem!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: @Mahsa I am glad to help you out

Comment: @Trenton_M really appreciated!